# Almacenar imagenes con angular 10 en laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, angular

Estoy tratando de almacenar una imagen en laravel mandandola por mi frontend desde angular, pero al momento de querer hacerlo o me la almacena incompleta o defectuosa.

Estoy usando formularios reactivos en angular, y he visto que para enviar la imagen crean un formdata por lo que no logro entender muy bien la parte del por que se realiza con formdata, pero de la manera en la que lo estoy haciendo me funciona a medias, ya que la momento de que se almacena en una carpeta dentro de public, esta se almacena a la mitad, o deforme. espero alguien me pueda ayudar.

En mi formulario tengo un input comun que al tener algun cambio arroja un evento en el componente

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="logo" (change)="fileEvent($event)" required>
```

En el componente creo mi formulario de la siguiente manera

```
companyForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  id: [1],
  tradename: ['', Validators.required],
  rfc: ['', Validators.required],
  sat_name: ['', Validators.required],
  phone: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  zip_code: ['', Validators.required],
  calle: ['', Validators.required],
  numero_exterior: ['', Validators.required],
  numero_interior: [''],
  asentamiento: ['', Validators.required],
  municipio: ['', Validators.required],
  estado: ['', Validators.required],
  ciudad: ['', Validators.required],
  pais: ['', Validators.required],
  logo: ['', Validators.required],
});
```

En el componente al momento de comenzar el evento

```
fileEvent(e){
  let reader = new FileReader();
  if(e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
    let file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
    reader.onload = () => { 
      this.companyForm.get('logo').setValue({
        filename: file.name,
        filetype: file.type,
        value: (<string>reader.result).split(',')[1]
      })
    };
  }
}
```

Esto es lo que contiene value sin colocarle el [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS1QM.png)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el submit y enviar el formulario al servicio es de la siguiente manera

```
onSubmit(){
  console.log(this.companyForm.value);
  this._companyService.create(this.token, this.companyForm.value).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response.status == 'success') {
        console.log(response);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(<any>error);
    }
  )
}
```

En el servicio lo recibo, lo transformo a json y lo envio de la siguiente manera

```
create(token, company): Observable<any>{
    let json = JSON.stringify(company);
    console.log(json);
    let params = "json=" + json;

    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded').set('Authorization', token);

    return this._http.post(this.url + 'empresa', params, {headers:headers});
}
```

Y ya en mi backend con laravel lo guardo de la siguiente manera

```
    $json = $request->input('json', null);
$params = json_decode($json);
$params_array = json_decode($json, true);

$company = new Company();
$company->tradename = $params->tradename;
$company->rfc = $params->rfc;
$company->sat_name = $params->sat_name;
$company->phone = $params->phone;
$company->email = $params->email;
$company->zip_code = $params->zip_code;
$company->calle = $params->calle;
$company->numero_exterior = $params->numero_exterior;
$company->numero_interior = $params->numero_interior;
$company->asentamiento = $params->asentamiento;
$company->municipio = $params->municipio;
$company->estado = $params->estado;
$company->ciudad = $params->ciudad;
$company->pais = $params->pais;

$folderPath = "uploads/";
$image_type_aux = explode("image/", $params_array['logo']['filetype']);
$image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
$image_base64 = base64_decode($params_array['logo']['value']);
$file = $folderPath . uniqid() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
$company->logo = $file;

$company->save();
```

Asi es como consigo que se almacene :/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: (<string>reader.result).split(',')[1] puede que halla otra (,) en todo tu string y halla ['dsadsa','23782','hjkhsad']. Obten el index con indexOf de la posición de la primera (,) y toma el substring a partir del index (<string>reader.result).substring(index)

Comment: @UrielManzano acabo de colocar una imagen con el resulto sin colocarle el [1] en value: (<string>reader.result).split(',')

Comment: Fijate si la imagen en base64 esta llegando bien, podes ver una preview con https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image